# Is there any option to improve the time efficiency of the this data normalization any further?

Tags: python, performance, time, max, list-comprehension

I have a matrix named tArray with shape (11, 512) and want to normalize the values in it. I see that the np.max() costs a lot time but I didn't find any option to improve it any further. Can the time efficiency of this following line of code be improved?:

```
tArray = np.array([[val/tArray[i][sqLen-1] for val in tArray[i]] if i not in [1,2] else [val/np.max(tArray[i][:sqLen-1]) for val in tArray[i]] for i in range(len(tArray))])
```

to reproduce:

````
tArray = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(11, 512))
tArray = np.array([[val/tArray[i][512-1] for val in tArray[i]] if i not in [1,2] else [val/np.max(tArray[i][:512-1]) for val in tArray[i]] for i in range(len(tArray))])```
````

Comment: What is `sqLen` and `collsToIgnore` ? Can you share a reproducible example ?

Comment: `sqLen` has the value 512

Comment: A reproducible example ? What about `collsToIgnore` ?

Comment: a list of column indexes, just updated it

Comment: Could you break/format that far too long line into several to make it more readable? By yourself or maybe with https://black.vercel.app/

Comment: "and want to normalize the values in it." - Meaning what, exactly? There are many things that can be called normalization, and it isn't at all obvious why indices `1` and `2` of an array dimension that's 11 long would be special. (Just to make sure, you understand that array indexing is 0-based, yes?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is ~**180X** speedup improvement approach:

Note, for the shape of your input array `[512-1]` is the same as `[-1]` (last column) and `[:512-1]` is the same as `[:-1]`.

The main condition of your loop `if i not in [1,2] else` tells that the aggregations/calculations are implied for exactly 3 slices:
`[0]` (first row), `[1:3]` (rows 1 and 2) and the remaining rows `[3:]`.

So instead of iterating over each row and recalculating each column we can apply the needed operations for 3 sequential slices at once in vectorized manner and eventually concatenate the results with [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) routine:

```
np.vstack((tArray[0]/tArray[0,-1], tArray[1:3]/tArray[1:3,:-1].max(1)[:,None], tArray[3:]/tArray[3:,-1][:,None]))
```

---

Let's see on measurements:

```
tArray = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(11, 512)) # input array
```

---

```
In [165]: %timeit tArray1 = np.array([[val/tArray[i][512-1] for val in tArray[i]] if i not in [1,2] else [val/np.max
     ...: (tArray[i][:512-1]) for val in tArray[i]] for i in range(len(tArray))])
4.54 ms ± 23.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [171]: %timeit new_arr = np.vstack((tArray[0]/tArray[0,-1], tArray[1:3]/tArray[1:3,:-1].max(1)[:,None], tArray[3:]/tAr
     ...: ray[3:,-1][:,None]))
25.5 µs ± 264 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

Of course, `tArray1` and `new_arr` have the same content:

```
In [173]: tArray1
Out[173]: 
array([[ 8.11111111,  2.33333333,  9.33333333, ...,  0.44444444,
         5.22222222,  1.        ],
       [ 0.76767677,  0.77777778,  0.72727273, ...,  0.58585859,
         0.29292929,  0.09090909],
       [ 0.36363636,  0.85858586,  0.35353535, ...,  0.06060606,
         0.48484848,  0.55555556],
       ...,
       [ 1.875     ,  2.04166667,  0.29166667, ...,  0.20833333,
         0.58333333,  1.        ],
       [ 0.28735632,  0.11494253,  0.37931034, ...,  0.50574713,
         0.74712644,  1.        ],
       [ 5.625     , 10.5       ,  0.5       , ...,  2.125     ,
         0.75      ,  1.        ]])

In [174]: new_arr
Out[174]: 
array([[ 8.11111111,  2.33333333,  9.33333333, ...,  0.44444444,
         5.22222222,  1.        ],
       [ 0.76767677,  0.77777778,  0.72727273, ...,  0.58585859,
         0.29292929,  0.09090909],
       [ 0.36363636,  0.85858586,  0.35353535, ...,  0.06060606,
         0.48484848,  0.55555556],
       ...,
       [ 1.875     ,  2.04166667,  0.29166667, ...,  0.20833333,
         0.58333333,  1.        ],
       [ 0.28735632,  0.11494253,  0.37931034, ...,  0.50574713,
         0.74712644,  1.        ],
       [ 5.625     , 10.5       ,  0.5       , ...,  2.125     ,
         0.75      ,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: There is a problem with this. The max should be taken along `axis=1` otherwise it doesn't match the OP's calculation for one of the two rows `1:3`. But then if you replace with `... .max(1)` you get a shape incompatibility; must use `[:. None]` there as well.

Comment: @PierreD, if you say that there's wrong axis, than why the OPs final array and mine are matched ?

Comment: It matches by chance. This is because, with reasonably high probability, the max of each row is very often 99 or 98 in the OP's setup. In particular, you'll very often (but not always) observe that `tArray[1].max() == tArray[2].max() == tArray[1:3].max()`. Try e.g. with either `np.random.uniform(...)` or `np.random.randint(1, 100_000)`: then OP's result and yours will most likely be different.

Comment: @PierreD, ok, it seems you're right. Fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of denominators, replacing the ones in the selected rows with the max. Then divide the whole matrix by this array of denominators (you need to transpose the matrix to do this then transpose it back again).

```
t = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(11, 512))
ignore = [1, 2] 
denoms = t[..., -1].copy()
denoms[ignore] = t[ignore, :-1].max(axis=1)
result = (t.T / denoms).T
```

This seems to be slightly faster than the `vstack` solution and also allows you to choose which rows to select a bit more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for a 350x speedup (560x on floats)?

```py
def f(a):
    d = a[:, -1].copy()
    d[1:3] = a[1:3, :-1].max(1)
    return a / d[:, None]
```

On `float` arrays, it's twice faster than @Roman's answer. I would argue that it is also a bit easier to read.

```py
a = np.random.uniform(1, 100, size=(11, 512))

%timeit np.vstack((a[0]/a[0,-1], a[1:3,:]/a[1:3,:-1].max(), a[3:,:]/a[3:,-1][:,None]))
24.4 µs ± 102 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit f(a)
11.8 µs ± 22.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

On `int` arrays, the difference is a bit less drastic (60% faster).